# Tensorflow can't detect GPU when invoked by Ray worker

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, distributed-computing, multi-gpu

When I try the following code sample for using Tensorflow with Ray, Tensorflow fails to detect the GPU's on my machine when invoked by the "remote" worker but it does find the GPU's when invoked "locally". I put "remote" and "locally" in scare quotes because everything is running on my desktop which has two GPU's and is running Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed Tensorflow using the `tensorflow-gpu` Anaconda package.

The `local_network` seems to be responsible for these messages in the logs:

```
2018-01-26 17:24:33.149634: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro M5000, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
2018-01-26 17:24:33.149642: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Quadro M5000, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0)
```

And the `remote_network` seems to be responsible for this message:

```
2018-01-26 17:24:34.309270: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:406] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
```

Why is Tensorflow able to detect the GPU in one case but not the other?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import ray

ray.init()

BATCH_SIZE = 100
NUM_BATCHES = 1
NUM_ITERS = 201

class Network(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Seed TensorFlow to make the script deterministic.
        tf.set_random_seed(0)
        # Define the inputs.
        x_data = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32)
        y_data = tf.constant(y, dtype=tf.float32)
        # Define the weights and computation.
        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
        y = w * x_data + b
        # Define the loss.
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
        self.grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss)
        self.train = optimizer.apply_gradients(self.grads)
        # Define the weight initializer and session.
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        # Additional code for setting and getting the weights
        self.variables = ray.experimental.TensorFlowVariables(self.loss, self.sess)
        # Return all of the data needed to use the network.
        self.sess.run(init)

    # Define a remote function that trains the network for one step and returns the
    # new weights.
    def step(self, weights):
        # Set the weights in the network.
        self.variables.set_weights(weights)
        # Do one step of training. We only need the actual gradients so we filter over the list.
        actual_grads = self.sess.run([grad[0] for grad in self.grads])
        return actual_grads

    def get_weights(self):
        return self.variables.get_weights()

# Define a remote function for generating fake data.
@ray.remote(num_return_vals=2)
def generate_fake_x_y_data(num_data, seed=0):
    # Seed numpy to make the script deterministic.
    np.random.seed(seed)
    x = np.random.rand(num_data)
    y = x * 0.1 + 0.3
    return x, y

# Generate some training data.
batch_ids = [generate_fake_x_y_data.remote(BATCH_SIZE, seed=i) for i in range(NUM_BATCHES)]
x_ids = [x_id for x_id, y_id in batch_ids]
y_ids = [y_id for x_id, y_id in batch_ids]
# Generate some test data.
x_test, y_test = ray.get(generate_fake_x_y_data.remote(BATCH_SIZE, seed=NUM_BATCHES))

# Create actors to store the networks.
remote_network = ray.remote(Network)
actor_list = [remote_network.remote(x_ids[i], y_ids[i]) for i in range(NUM_BATCHES)]
local_network = Network(x_test, y_test)

# Get initial weights of local network.
weights = local_network.get_weights()

# Do some steps of training.
for iteration in range(NUM_ITERS):
    # Put the weights in the object store. This is optional. We could instead pass
    # the variable weights directly into step.remote, in which case it would be
    # placed in the object store under the hood. However, in that case multiple
    # copies of the weights would be put in the object store, so this approach is
    # more efficient.
    weights_id = ray.put(weights)
    # Call the remote function multiple times in parallel.
    gradients_ids = [actor.step.remote(weights_id) for actor in actor_list]
    # Get all of the weights.
    gradients_list = ray.get(gradients_ids)

    # Take the mean of the different gradients. Each element of gradients_list is a list
    # of gradients, and we want to take the mean of each one.
    mean_grads = [sum([gradients[i] for gradients in gradients_list]) / len(gradients_list) for i in range(len(gradients_list[0]))]

    feed_dict = {grad[0]: mean_grad for (grad, mean_grad) in zip(local_network.grads, mean_grads)}
    local_network.sess.run(local_network.train, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    weights = local_network.get_weights()

    # Print the current weights. They should converge to roughly to the values 0.1
    # and 0.3 used in generate_fake_x_y_data.
    if iteration % 20 == 0:
        print("Iteration {}: weights are {}".format(iteration, weights))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GPUs are cut off by [`ray.remote`](http://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remote) decorator itself. From its source code:

```py
def remote(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    num_cpus = kwargs["num_cpus"] if "num_cpus" in kwargs else 1
    num_gpus = kwargs["num_gpus"] if "num_gpus" in kwargs else 0  # !!!
    ...
```

So the following call effectively sets `num_gpus=0`:

```py
remote_network = ray.remote(Network)
```

Ray API is a bit strange, and you can't simply say `ray.remote(Network, num_gpus=2)` (though that's exactly what you want). Here's what I did and it seems to work on my machine:

```py
ray.init(num_gpus=2)

...

@ray.remote(num_gpus=2)
class RemoteNetwork(Network):
    pass

actor_list = [RemoteNetwork.remote(x_ids[i],y_ids[i]) for i in range(NUM_BATCHES)]
```